# Protecting jeans from saddle rub?

Tags: clothes

I am looking at ways to deal with jeans aging prematurely due to saddle rub. While I could change clothing (not nessarily an option), as suggested in an [older thread](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/18508/how-to-minimize-wear-on-pants), I am wondering if there is such a thing as shorts to put over jeans than can quickly be removed. If not, has anyone experimented to see if this would help diminish the issue?

Comment: Not a solution for most and because of that a comment only: Change to a different kind of bike, since I ride a recumbent I do not have the jeans damage anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could switch to a saddle that isn't as abrasive. That's one of the reasons people like leather saddles such as Brookes -- even if they're more expensive and heavier than plastic wonders.  The leather saddles also breathe and wick moisture and I've found that wet cloth abrades much faster than dry cloth.

[image: Brookes leather saddle]

There are also neoprene saddle covers which might reduce friction by allowing more slippage, but I've always found the squishy movement they cause to be more uncomfortable than comfortable.
[image: Generic saddle cover]

ps. Many cyclists consider saddle worn clothing to be a mark of pride.

Answer (score 2):

You could easily throw a pair of shorts on over your jeans. It would look silly, but it'd get the job done.